# New to data structures

Tags: c++, string, data-structures, c++11

An exercise question from c++ primer 5th edition asked to write an own version of `sales_data` class.

Here's how I did

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct sales data
{
    string bookno;
    unsigned int books sold;
    double revenue;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Running this gives the following errors:

```
Variable sales_data has an initializer, but an incomplete type

String was not declared in this scope (How do I declare a string?)
```

Comment: It should be `std::string` - you're forgetting the namespace qualifier.

Comment: I did not know struct belonged to std. Anyways, it still gives the same errors.

Answer (score 7):

**First problem**: you forgot an underscore (or some other character) in the names `sales_data` and `books_sold`. Identifiers cannot contain whitespaces in C++:

```
struct sales_data
//          ^

unsigned int books_sold;
//                ^
```

**Second problem**: you should qualify `string` with the namespace it belongs to:

```
    std::string bookno;
//  ^^^^^
```

Or have a `using` declaration for it before you use the unqualified `string` name:

```
using std::string;
```

This is how your program should look like with all the above fixes:

```
#include <iostream> // You don't seem to need this for this program
#include <string>

struct sales_data
{
    std::string bookno;
    unsigned int books_sold;
    double revenue;
};

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Added using namespace std; Still the same errors. Added the underscore too. Didn't help.

Comment: Okay, now it says error: expected unqualified-id before struct

Comment: @judas: If this answers your question, could you please consider marking the answer as accepted? (or any other answer you may prefer by other users, of course)

Answer (score 1):

This

```
struct sales data
```

Should be

```
struct sales_data
```

Note the underscore.
Spaces aren't legal in identifiers or type names.

Comment: @user1929959, yes that too.

Comment: Okay, now it says error: expected unqualified-id before struct